# What are the current champions in the modified busy-beaver-competition?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

The maximum number of ones that a halting turing machine with $n$ states and $2$ symbols can write down on an initially empty tape , if the ones must form a single block, is usually denoted with $\sigma(n)$. The maximum number of steps should also differ from $S(n)$

> Does anyone know a site with a survey of the current champions in this category ?

For $n\le 3$, the values do not differ because there are busy beavers forming a single block. But for $4$ states, the champion I found online does not produce a single block, neither does the current busy beaver I found with $5$ states.

Comment: Did you check the article [The Busy Beaver Competition: a historical survey](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00396880/file/tpm335.pdf)?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Verny nice and interesting article. But I did not find anything about the current record-holders in this special category.

Comment: You should ask the author of the article. He might know the answer to your question or possibly give you some hint.